# Navigation drawer, fragments and hardware back button

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

Is it possible to always navigate to main fragment on back button click?

I tried something like this

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

            super.onBackPressed();
           FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

           fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();

    }
```

It doesn't works.

So basically every time someone click the back button it should display Launcher Fragment and if user is already at Laucner fragment it should exit the app

Comment: Why don't you use `replace` with the launcher fragment in onBackPressed method? It might resolve your issue.

Comment: This is why I am not using it: http://screencast.com/t/99UNoe3GzUg